# Error: knex: Required configuration option 'client' is missing

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Node.js, please help me.

What is wrong?

Using typescript, SQLite3 and Knex, with migration.
I get the error when running *"yarn knex: migrate"* or *"knex migrate: latest"*:

**$ knex migrate:latest**
**Requiring external module ts-node/register**
**Error: knex: Required configuration option 'client' is missing**

These are my files:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --transpile-only --ignore-watch node-modules --respawn 
src/server.ts",
    "knex:migrate": "knex --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:latest",
    "knex:migrate:rollback": "knex --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:rollback"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "espress": "^0.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "knex": "^0.95.4",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

knexfile.ts:

```
import path from'path';

module.exports = {
  cliente: 'sqlite3',

  connection: {
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'resp.sqlite')
  },

  migrations: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
  },
  
  useNullAsDefault: true,
};
```

Migration 00_create_organizacoes.ts:

```
import knex from 'knex';

export async function up(knex: knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('organizacoes', table => {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('razaosocial_org').notNullable();
    table.integer('atividade_org').notNullable();
    table.timestamp('criacao_org').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp('atualizacao_org').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  });
}

export async function down(knex: knex) {
  return knex.schema.droptable('organizacoes');
};
```

My file structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMPJm.png)

Unsuccessful in other treatments.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: $ knex migrate:latest
Requiring external module ts-node/register
Error: knex: Required configuration option 'client' is missing.

Comment: I was not able to progress in this problem. Does anyone already go through this to help?
I tried to reinstall the dependencies but I always get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in your knexfile.ts
The name of the missing property is `client` and not `cliente`

Answer (score 0):

The `Requiring external module ts-node/register` message you get is not the issue, the issue is that in the `knexfile.ts` the client property is not read. From the example above change the `cliente` property to `client` and it is fixed.

What if you have no spelling error, client exist in your configuration, and you are getting this message? Are you using a `env` file? If yes, In your `knexfile.ts` print the value from your `env` file. If it returns `undefined`, it means that no value was read for the `env` file. Check if you have the `dotenv` package installed and configured properly. Also check that your `env` file has a key called client and the value is available and in the `knexfile.ts` ensure you are calling the right key from your `env`.

Finally if the problem is not solved and every other thing is in-place, require dotenv in your `package.json` file before running a command as shown below.

```sh
"migrate:latest": "ts-node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js migrate:latest
```

The `ts-node -r dotenv/config` ensures that the details in the `env` file are added to the environment.
The `./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js` starts the knex cli so that the remaining part which is a knex command can be executed.